# What does my compiler error mean?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

My program compiles with `cc` but when I compile it with `$ gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O4` I get warnings that I don't understand:

```
miniShell.c: In function ‘main’:
miniShell.c:144:24: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time [enabled by default]
                 struct command cmd[] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };
```

What does the above mean? I have my declarations on the top of main for these variables:

```
        char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
        char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        char *less[] = { "less", 0 };
        struct command cmd[] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };
```

I have a global variable for command.

```
struct command
{
    char * const *argv;
};
```

Comment: @GregHewgill They are declared like this: `char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};`

Comment: Show the definition of `struct command`.

Comment: @RSahu `struct command cmd[] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `printenv` varies at runtime. Subsequent executions of your program may find that the location of that array changes.

In C89, the elements of an initializer list must be constant compile time expressions. Which that isn't.

In C99 and later, this restriction was relaxed. You can enable this with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`

Comment: How can I achieve it in C89?

Comment: It's not legal in C89. There are gcc extensions that support it, but `-pedantic` explicitly turns them off...

Comment: Then what are my options if I must compile with `-pedantic` if I want to rewrite my program to compile with `-pedantic` ?

Comment: Ok. Maybe it will work using `cmd[0].argv= printenv;
cmd[1].argv= sort;
cmd[2].argv= less;`

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm why don't you want to use `-std=c11` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is part of an exercise to learn C and obey the `-ansi` switch. Part of the agreement was that we compile using `gcc -ansi -O4 -pedantic` so I first compile using `cc` and then fix what is left.